# Huge delay in kafka stream processing

Tags: java, performance, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a stream topology as follows:

```
Topology topology = new Topology();

            //WS connection processor
    topology.addSource(WS_CONNECTION_SOURCE, new StringDeserializer(), new WebSocketConnectionEventDeserializer()
            , utilService.getTopicByType(TopicType.CONNECTION_EVENTS_TOPIC))
            .addProcessor(SESSION_PROCESSOR, WSUserSessionProcessor::new, WS_CONNECTION_SOURCE)
            .addStateStore(sessionStoreBuilder, SESSION_PROCESSOR)
            .addSink(WS_STATUS_SINK, utilService.getTopicByType(TopicType.ONLINE_STATUS_TOPIC),
                    stringSerializer, stringSerializer
            , SESSION_PROCESSOR)

            //WS session routing
            .addSource(WS_ROUTING_BY_SESSION_SOURCE, new StringDeserializer(), new StringDeserializer(),
                    utilService.getTopicByType(TopicType.NOTIFICATION_TOPIC))
            .addProcessor(WS_ROUTING_BY_SESSION_PROCESSOR, WSSessionRoutingProcessor::new,
                    WS_ROUTING_BY_SESSION_SOURCE)
            .addStateStore(userConnectedNodesStoreBuilder, WS_ROUTING_BY_SESSION_PROCESSOR, SESSION_PROCESSOR);

    topology.addGlobalStore(serviceDiscoveryGlobalStoreBuilder, "WS_SERVICE_DISCOVERY", new StringDeserializer(),
            new ServiceDiscoveryEventDeserializer(), "ws-service-discovery", "WS_SERVICE_DISCOVERY_PROCESSOR",
            ServiceDiscoveryProcessor::new);
```

While analyzing logs, there is huge delay in messages coming in `WS_ROUTING_BY_SESSION_PROCESSOR` `process` method. Delay is of the order of 10+ seconds.

This is the configuration used in streams:

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.setProperty(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, kafkaServers);
    properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_RECORDS_CONFIG, "500");
    properties.setProperty(ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, "60000");
    properties.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
    properties.put(ConsumerConfig.REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, "60000");
    properties.put(ConsumerConfig.DEFAULT_API_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG, "60000");
```

Partitions for `NOTIFICATION_TOPIC` is 10 and number of stream threads is 10

Comment: Looking at the topology, it doesn't look like there should be any delay. Is it likely that the messages in the topic itself are having that delay?

Comment: As per my logs, producer has successfully sent message, but the stream app s receiving it in `process()` after long time

Comment: Ok. If it's on the topic, it shouldn't be taking that much delay. You could do a few things to debug (assuming you haven't already) :
* Reduce `ConsumerConfig.MAX_POLL_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG`
* Remove the Connection Processor sub-topology to isolate the problem